# REGEX to find first instance after set length

Tags: regex

I'm probably going to get pilloried for asking this question, but after searching and trying to figure out this regex on my own, I'm just tired of wasting time trying to figure out.  Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.  I frequently use editpad pro to to convert character strings so they will fit into a mainframe.

For instance, I want to convert a column of words from excel into an IN clause for sql.  The column is 5000 words or so.

I can easily copy and paste that into the text editor and then using find and replace convert that from a column of words to a single row with ',' separating each word.

Once that's done, though I want to use a regex to split this row before or after a comma after 70 characters have gone by.

```
(?P<start>^.{0,70})
```

This will give me the first 70 characters, but then I get stuck as I can't figure out how to create the next group to find all the characters up to the next comma so I can refer to it like this

```
(?P<start>^.{0,70})(?P<next>????,)
```

If I could get that, then I could create do a find and replace that would break it after the first comma that appears after the 70th character.

I know given the rest of the day I could figure it out, but I need to move on.  I've tried this before.  I would even be willing to only find the first 7o characters and then next few characters until the comma and then have to repeat the replace and find multiple times, if necessary, but I can not get the regex to work.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some sample data that I have added line breaks into as an example of what I want it to look like after the regex runs.

```
'Ability','Absence','Absolute','Absorb','Accident','Acclaim','Accompany',
'Accomplish','Achievement','Acquaintance','Acquire','Across','Acting','Address',
'Admire','Adorable','Advance','Advertisement','Afraid','Agriculture','Align',
'All','Allow','Allowance','Allowed','Alone','Aluminium','Always','America',
'Analyze','Android','Angle','Announce','Annual','Ant','Antarctica','Antler',
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the original text?

Comment: is https://regex101.com/r/cY8iB9/1 good?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider restricting your initial concatenation, but here's a solution to your specific implementation :

```
^.{0,70}[^,]*
```

This will select the first 70 characters (if available), then every character up to the one before the next comma.

I don't think you need groups here, but you can obviously add them to the regex :

```
(?P<start>^.{0,70})(?P<next>[^,]*)
```

Comment: (?P<start>^.{0,70})(P?<next>[^,]*) doesn't find anything in my text

Comment: I converted what you provided to

 (?P<start>^.{0,70}[^,]*) 

This correctly finds up to the first comma.  But when I try to add a Replace clause using

${start}(carriage return) I run into an unanticipated problem. because this finds the first string, does a replace, but now both the first line and second line match the search clause and a rerunning the find and replace starts duplicating text.

Comment: I hardly ever used named groups, so it's no wonder I made a mistake writing them. If you've got them running, please comment back so I can fix my answer. That said, I don't think you need them here : I would just search for `^.{0,70}[^,]*,` and replace with `\0\n`, adding a line feed after the matched 70+ characters

Comment: For the reiterated matches, just run your regex search/replace once and you'll be fine? I mean, the search position should be set at the end of the previously replaced text and the next match should not work on the previous line. I don't know your editor at all so it might be a parameter to set.

Comment: In order to do a find and replace in editpad pro you have to use named groups  e.g.  I use the following:

(?P<page>.+) (?P<tag>[0-9]+) (?P<english>.+) (?P<spanish>.+)
to take 4 columns of information that I copied out of an excel spreadsheet

Comment: and convert it into database insert statements using the following in the replace field:   


update <database>.table set id_user_last_updat = '<myid>, ts_last_update = current timestamp, no_change_version = no_change_version + 1, TX_TRANSLATION = '${english}' where ID_510_page_pf = '${page}' and co_511_lang_pf = 'EN' and no_tag_pk = ${tag};
update <database>.<table> set id_user_last_updat = 'myID', ts_last_update = current timestamp, no_change_version = no_change_version + 1, TX_TRANSLATION = '${spanish}' where ID_510_page_pf = '${page}' and co_511_lang_pf = 'ES' and no_tag_pk = ${tag};

Comment: Ok so you did well putting everything into a single group. Now you're saying your search/replace tool will match the replaced line again. Doesn't it have a `find/replace next` that would resume the search where it left? If not, I guess you'll have to look-ahead for additional characters in your search pattern so you're sure you're not matching an already processed line.

Comment: Although in all honesty, I'm beginning to think that using editpad might not be the best way. What I described would have worked well in Notepad++ or sed.

Comment: There's isn't a next to find because when you start you only have one row of text.  After the first find and replace is done you've got 2 rows of text and the criteria meets them both.  You are onto something with your comment, though, because I just need to make sure the first lines are excluded.

Comment: Even if you only have one line, you still have a position in term of numbers of characters. I'm surprised your editor doesn't offer continue searching after the text he just replaced (line feed included, so in the second line)